# Toggle addclass with jquery parent selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some items products in a grid.
I want that when i click on each icon from item, it will toggle a class '.active' and also remove class if others from others items are visible.

This is my script so far,  can add the class remove from others items but when i click on the same icon it doesn't toggle it (remove the class).

```js
$('.items #show-actions').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this).parent().parent('.items');
  var $that = $(this).closest('.items');
  $('.items').find('.actions').not($this).removeClass('active');
  $that.find('.actions').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```html
<ul class="products-grid row">
  <li class="items">
    <a href="somelink" class="product-image"><img src="/images/myimage.png" "/></a>
    <div class="product-info">
      <span id="show-actions" class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal visible-sm visible-xs ic"></span>
      <h2 class="product-brand">Test</h2>
      <div class="actions text-center hidden">
        <button class="btn-block">Ok</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="items">
    <a href="somelink" class="product-image"><img src="/images/myimage.png" "/></a>
    <div class="product-info">
      <span id="show-actions" class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal visible-sm visible-xs ic"></span>
      <h2 class="product-brand">Test</h2>
      <div class="actions text-center hidden">
        <button class="btn-block">Ok</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: could you set up a js fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove this row:

```
$('.items').find('.actions').not($this).removeClass('active');
```

Because in your function you first `remove` the class, and then `toggle` it. In this case, if the element already has `active` class, it will be removed first, and then `toggle` will add it again (it looks like the element still has an `active` class, because operations are very fast). I have removed the row as described above and added some styles to see the difference, so here is the working snippet (click on "Show Actions" to see the difference):

```js
$('.items #show-actions').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this).parent().parent('.items');
  var $that = $(this).closest('.items');
  $that.find('.actions').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.items #show-actions {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: royalblue;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products-grid row">
  <li class="items">
    <a href="somelink" class="product-image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c629327/v629327473/db66/r051joYFRX0.jpg" /></a>
    <div class="product-info">
      <span id="show-actions" class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal visible-sm visible-xs ic">Show Actions</span>
      <h2 class="product-brand">Test</h2>
      <div class="actions text-center hidden">
        <button class="btn-block">Ok</button>         
      </div>
    </div>    
  </li>
  <li class="items">
    <a href="somelink" class="product-image"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c629327/v629327473/db66/r051joYFRX0.jpg" /></a>
    <div class="product-info">
      <span id="show-actions" class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal visible-sm visible-xs ic">Show Actions</span>
      <h2 class="product-brand">Test</h2>
      <div class="actions text-center hidden">
        <button class="btn-block">Ok</button>         
      </div>
    </div>    
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't have duplicate ID's on any HTML page. I suggest you change #show-actions to a class for the  rather than an ID.

Second, you also have some extra quote marks in your img element.

Once you do that it's pretty simple.

```js
$('.show-actions').on('click', function() {
  var items = $('.items');
  
  items.removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().parent('.items').addClass('active');
  
});
```

```css
.active {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products-grid row">
        <li class="items">
            <a class="product-image"><img src="/images/myimage.png"/></a>
            <div class="product-info">
                <span class="show-actions glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal visible-sm visible-xs ic">TOGGLE ME</span>
                <h2 class="product-brand">Test</h2>
                <div class="actions text-center hidden">
                    <button class="btn-block">Ok</button>         
                </div>
            </div>    
        </li>
        <li class="items">
            <a class="product-image"><img src="/images/myimage.png"/></a>
            <div class="product-info">
                <span class="show-actions glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal visible-sm visible-xs ic">TOGGLE ME</span>
                <h2 class="product-brand">Test</h2>
                <div class="actions text-center hidden">
                    <button class="btn-block">Ok</button>         
                </div>
            </div>    
        </li>
    </ul>
```